# Libvirt and new syntax for Qemu override / commandline on gpu passtrough

Tags: libvirt

Until qemu 6.1.0 (and 6.2.0 with capability_filters = [ "device.json" ] in qemu.conf )
this configuration works fine for gpu passtrough on old Windows 2000 machine. The pulseaudio way, make the sound not out of sync.

```
<qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-object'/>
    <qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=mouse,evdev=//dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if01-event-mouse'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-object'/>
    <qemu:arg value='input-linux,id=kbd,evdev=/dev/input/by-id/usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd,grab_all=on,repeat=on'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-set'/>
    <qemu:arg value='device.hostdev1.x-vga=on'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='ac97,audiodev=ac97'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-audiodev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='pa,id=ac97,server=unix:/tmp/pulse-socket'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_DRV' value='pa'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_DAC_FIXED_FREQ' value='48000'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_DAC_TRY_POLL' value='0'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_ADC_FIXED_FREQ' value='48000'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_ADC_TRY_POLL' value='0'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_AUDIO_TIMER_PERIOD' value='1000'/>
    <qemu:env name='QEMU_PA_SERVER' value='/tmp/pulse-socket'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
```

but after 6.2.0 this configuration doesn't work anymore, return error "QEMU: there is no device "hostdev1" defined"

The new syntax is like this

```
  <qemu:override>
    <qemu:device alias='hostdev1'>
      <qemu:frontend>
        <qemu:property name='x-vga' type='bool' value='true'/>
      </qemu:frontend>
    </qemu:device>
  </qemu:override>
```

the vga works perfect, but the ac97 card disappear.

I have tried this

```
  <qemu:override>
    <qemu:device alias='hostdev1'>
      <qemu:frontend>
        <qemu:property name='x-vga' type='bool' value='true'/>
      </qemu:frontend>
    </qemu:device>
    <qemu:device alias='ac97'>
      <qemu:frontend>
        <qemu:property name='audiodev' type='string' value='id=ac97,driver=pa'/>
      </qemu:frontend>
    </qemu:device>
  </qemu:override>
</domain>
```

but nothing, the vm start without sound card, reading the log the "-device ac97,audiodev=ac97 " is missing (so no soundcard on the vm)

FAQ:

Why don't use hdmi for sound? Simple: my monitor has only a vga port

Why don't use ac97 from libvirt? Because I don't know if is possible to setup the pulseaudio socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I use this workaround.I compile old qemu (6.2) on another dir (/opt/qemu6) and using this binary instead the new in /usr (is bad...but works fine). So I can Use the old syntax on this vm only.